# Is there a way to define a dynamic bounding box for the field of view?

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, camera

Edit 2: I found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018710/calculate-near-far-plane-vertices-using-three-frustum). The near and far planes compound the bounding box of the camera.

I have a Perspective Camera and multiple set of points (SphereGeometry) in the space and I want to define a bounding box according to what is visible in the field of view, so that I only need to load the points that are currently visible in the space according to the camera settings.

My problem when defining the bounding box is that I don't have a reference point between the camera position and what I'm currently looking at. For example, if the camera is at the position *v1*(20, 20, 20), and let's say the mid point of my set of points is set at *v2*(5, 5, 5). Then, I can define the initial point of my bounding box as this mid point v2(5, 5, 5) , and I could create a bounding box (square) with  size `(v1-v2)/2`. But once I start moving the camera I lose this reference initial point, and I don't know how to obtain a distance parameter to define a proper bounding box of "what is currently visible".

Every time I move the camera I need to know the **size** of the bounding box and its **position** so that it represents as accurate as possible "what is currently visible" in the field of view.

One possible solution could be to translate the initial point v2(5, 5, 5) following every camera movement, is there any way to do this or something similar?

Edit:

So far I've been able to replicate @TheJim01 's code into my component, but I think this solution is not what I was looking for or I'm not able to understand it properly. I'm adding some images next to better explain what is going on.

In the next image I have a set of points of various colors, the 8 brown points represent each of the `worldBoxCorners` before performing a `worldToLocal` transformation. Which fits the whole space as it should.

[image: worldBoxCorners before transform]

Next, I render `worldBoxCorners` after the transformation. I do not understand how the bounding box is moved or how can I use it.

[image]

What I'm looking for is, for example if I zoom in into the space in the greener zone, to obtain a bounding box alike the last image. 
The point is to only load the points that are within the field of view, but for that I need to define a bounding box. When I say loading the points, I mean that only the points that are visible should be loaded from the **backend** (not talking about rendering here).

[image]

This solution provides a perfect bounding box for the current loaded space. What I'm missing on is how to define a new bounding box for a given loaded space according to camera parameters change (zoom in/out or rotations).

Comment: Adrià mentions me because I had originally submitted an answer, but I had misunderstood the question, so I deleted it.

Comment: Look at the [`Frustum`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Frustum) class. You can use `Frustum.setFromMatrix` with the camera's `projectionMatrix` to define the viewing Frustum for your current camera view. Then use `Frustum.containsPoint` and `Frustum.intersectsSphere` to see which spheres fall within the view. You can then build your new bounding box from those.

Comment: I think I found what I'm looking for. The Frustum class creates 6 planes that represent the camera's field of view. I want the bounding box to change in relation to the camera movement, not the current loaded space, it should be possible to intersect the planes to create a bounding box from the camera's perspective, am I correct?

Comment: Technically, yes, but for a `PerspectiveCamera`, the frustum is going to have angled sides (a [square frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum)). If you want a _box_ you will need to massage the information into the shape you want.

Comment: Could you resend me your initial answer please? Also, should I delete this post? I found what i was looking for here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018710/calculate-near-far-plane-vertices-using-three-frustum)

Comment: My original answer does not apply to your question, so re-adding it would not benefit the question/answer format of Stack Overflow. I also don't recommend deleting your question, because others may word their own question similarly. You can help those searchers find the solution you used by **editing** your question. Put the link you shared at the top so it's easy to find, and share how it answered your question.